# How do you authenticate to your GAE project from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google App Engine project with access restricted to "Google Apps Accounts". I would like to access this via URLFetch in Google Script for a Google Sheets custom function.

What is the best way to authenticate this call? Or associate these projects to allow access.

Comment: Have you tried the library at https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2 ? The example is for the Google Drive API, but should also work for other oauth2 connections, including App Engine.

Comment: A quick and easy way is with a custom URL and query string.  The secret query string gets authenticated.  Others not.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Thanks, do you know what scope I would use for my specific project? I thought this was only for Google APIs.

Comment: @GAEfan I would then need to make an exception in the YAML for this file. I guess that works.